# EJB/JPA Transaction Boundaries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, ejb-3.0

I was reading 
[EJB Transaction boundary and Transaction boundary](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html)

Lets concentrate on `RequiresNew Attribute`.

Here is the modified diagram from the link

[image]

So let say `method-B` is annotated with `RequiredNew attribute`.

so according to theory when `method-A` calls `method-B` a new transaction will be start and the already started transaction will be suspended, and when `method-B` returns the new transaction will be committed.

---

Now consider that in section `S1` we create a jpa entity using `entitymanager.persist()` and now we pass this entity to `method-B` which set the `name` field of the entity.

Now when we return from `method-B` how can it `commit` the transaction as in db, the entity is not being committed by the suspended transaction started by `method-A` ?

---

PS: Db running in read-committed isolation level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens in this scenario is governed by:

1. The JPA Persistence Context and its relationship to JTA transactions.
2. The behaviour of Java’s “*pass-by-reference*” *like* parameter passing on local interfaces.
   (See note on pass-by-reference at the end of this answer)

Creating an Entity Manager with the `@PersistenceContext` annotation leads to the creation of a Transaction-Scoped entity manager and associated persistence context as defined by your `persistence.xml` file. The context will keep track of the entities of the types specified in your `persistence.xml`. An entity becomes managed in that context after it is persisted, found (`em.find()`) or merged. The context will be associated with the currently running JTA transaction. When this transaction ends, the changes present in the persistence context can be flushed and committed - or rolled-back if the transaction itself rolls back.

In the example scenario assume Bean2’s local interface is used. When `Bean2-MethodB` is called a new transaction is started since the method is annotated with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)`. The transaction of the calling method is suspended. No persistence context is associated with the newly created transaction. However, the entity passed in will refer to the same instance of the entity processed by `Bean1-MethodA`, and this instance is a managed entity in the persistence context of Bean1’s Entity Manager.  So, even though the transaction associated to this persistence context is suspended, there are no restrictions on modifying that entity from within another transaction.

So, the nominal sequence of events is;

1. `Bean1-MethodA` is called, TransactionA starts.
2. Transaction-Scoped Entity Manager created, persistence context associated with TransactionA.
3. `Bean1-MethodA` calls `Bean2MethodB` and passes in ’entity’ as a parameter.
4. New Transaction – TransactionB starts, TransactionA suspended.
5. `Bean2-MethodB` modifies field  `entity.name`.
6. Bean2-MethodB finishes and TransactionB commits.
7. TransactionB JTA persistent resources commit - *entity* is in persistence context associated with TransactionA and so is not committed.
8. Bean1-MethodA resumes as does its associated TransactionA.
9. Entity changes made in `Bean2-MethodB` are visible to `Bean1-MethodA` and the persistence context
10. `Bean1-MethodA` finishes, TransactionA commits and persistence context changes are flushed/committed to DB
11. --> DB contains field change made in `Bean2-MethodB`

**What happens when Bean2-MehodB’s Transaction rolls-back?**

It is worth noting that if entity field changes are made in `Bean2-MethodB`, and `Bean2-MethodB’s` transaction rolls-back, changes to class fields are not reverted. Any JTA resources will be rolled-back, but the entity field changes would still be reflected in the DB If `Bean1-MehodA` completes successfully, leading to potential inconsistencies. It maybe that real world problems might force such a solution, but probably better to modify entities in the transaction that can roll those changes back.

***The above scenarios were tested on eclipse-mars/WildFly8.2/HibernateJPA/Derby***

**Working with Remote EJB calls**

Here, the entity parameter is serialised resulting in a copy of the entity in `Bean2-MethodB`. This copy is not the same object as used in `Bean1-MethodA`, it is a detached entity and is not shared with `Bean1-MethodA`. (This is sometimes known as *pass-by-value*, see note at the end of this answer). In order for changes to be reflected in `Bean1-MethodA’s` persistence context the entity would need to be returned to `Bean1-MethodA` and then merged into the persistence context using the Entity Manager. This merging would be required regardless of whether or not the remote ejb call was made within a transaction.

**Note on “Pass-by-reference” and “Pass-by-value”.**

All parameters in java are pass by value by definition. For a good - extended - discussion on Stack overflow see [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). What’s important here  is that for local interfaces, Java passes a copy of the reference – a pointer - to the shared instance – and this is what people often understand as “pass-by-reference”. Remote interfaces create a copy of the entity instance at the remote end so the calling method has no visibility of any changes to this copy. This is sometimes known as pass-by-value.

Comment: Just got a JAVA anxiety attack after reading your answer.. thx for the explaination

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2410148/user2410148 - You're welcome - yes a litttle bit scary.Do you think you could edit the title of you're question to something like - EJB/JPA Transaction Boundaries - ? As this more accurately reflects what we have here. Thanks.